# Alternate way to do Iterative name/variables in Pythonic while loop

Tags: python, variables, loops, iteration

So I know that it is a kind of pythonic heresy to modify a variable name while iterating over it but I have been searching for a good pythonic way to do this and can figure it out. In statistical programming (Stata, SAS), code like this is common:

```
for x in 1/y:
gen a`x'=0
```

and this would give you y variables, a1,a2,a3....ay all equal to 0.

I have seen other posts say that to do something like this you can create a library and call all of these values but what if you have an indefinite (finite) number of values?

In particular in the example below (which is the beginnings of a code to perform simple row-echelon reduction), I would like to create iterative variables (see the second-to-last line) with ax where x is equal to 0 (so a0) on the first iteration, 1 (or a1) on the second iteration and so on all the way up to ax.

I dont see a way to do this with dictionaries because I would have to specify the number of entries in it first. Maybe my understanding here is flawed but this is how I think of it.

```
def cmultadd(n, j, k, const):
    out = eye(n)
    out[j,k] = const
    return out  

def rowred(a):
    numrows = len(a)-1
    x=0
    while x<=numrows:
        ax=sp.dot(cmultadd(3,x,0,-ax[x+1,0]/ax[0,0]), a(x-1)); ax
        x=x+1
```

Can someone kindly explain a pythonic way to do what I am trying to do with the ax variable in the second to last line here? And (imaginary) bonus points if you can explain it in a way that makes sense given the first example (from stata) :)

Thanks.

Comment: Use lists. `ax` -> `a[x]`.

Comment: Dictionaries do not require you to specify their size upfront.  I wouldn't use dictionaries though because of the overhead of searching through string keys compared to @sweeneyrod suggestion of lists.

Comment: What is the type of the `a` parameter in `rowred()`?  Could you provide an example input?  I assume it is a matrix, but what type, `scipy.array`/`numpy.array`, `list` of `list`s, etc?

Answer (score 0):

For the first example,

> ```
> for x in 1/y:
> gen a`x'=0
> ```

you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate a(x) = 0, for x in [0, y]

```
a = [0 for x in range(y)]
```

or call a function or some other math

```
a = [math.pow(x, 2) for x in range(y)]
```

The second example is confusing, `ax` is referenced before it is defined and `a` is called like a function instead of indexed like a `list` or `sp.array`.

Maybe look at reduced row echelon form in python from [rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Reduced_row_echelon_form#Python).